# Не добавляется товар в корзину, ошибка NoReverseMatch at /cart/, что делать?

Tags: python, html, css, django, интернет-магазин

Всем добрый вечер!
Создаю интернет-магазин на django. Решил сделать корзину.После нажатия на кнопку "Добавить в корзину",[image: Добавить в корзину]

выскакивает ошибка "NoReverseMatch at /cart/
Reverse for 'delete_from_cart' with keyword arguments '{'slug': 'notebooks'}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['remove\-from\-cart/(?P[^/]+)/(?P[^/]+)/$']"[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Помогите пожалуйста!

Ссылка на проект https://disk.yandex.ru/d/mwvxgboe4yd30Q

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Покажите связанный с проблемой код

Comment: Я если честно, сам не понял в чём именно проблема.
В вопросе вставил ссылку на проект.
Спасибо вам!

Comment: Тогда добавьте код из следующих файлов models.py, views.py, forms.py (если есть) serializers.py (если есть) и urls.py , что бы можно было понять где возможная ошибка. Но я предполагаю, что это ошибка в url и их обработки

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас в mainapp.urls добавлен лишний слэш (/), попробуйте убрать:

```
path('add-to-cart//<str:slug>/', AddToCartView.as_view(), name='add_to_cart'),
```